# How to set a private static class variable to the one passed as input parameter

Tags: java, user-interface

I defined a private static class variable as followed

```
    private static PApplet processing;
```

and I have a method

```
    public static void setup(PApplet processing)
```

How do I set the processing class variable to the one passed as input parameter?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass {

    private static PApplet processing;

    public static void setup(PApplet processing) {
        SomeClass.processing = processing;
    }
}
```